# Two functions onclick, one of them with click event inside jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have 2 functions onclick like this:

```
<td ... onClick='clickedTD();counterFunction();questionsClick("+json_q[i].id+");' ... </td>";
```

And when I click on it my questionsClick() functions works but my clickedTD() function works on the second click.

clickedTD:

```
function clickedTD()
{
$(".questionsClass").click(function()
{
    $(".questionsClass").css("background-color","#eee");
    $(".questionsClass").css("color","black");

    $(this).css("background-color","#5bc0de");
    $(this).css("color","white");
});
}
```

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Because your `clickedTD()` is creating a function to work on contiuning clicks.

Comment: So how should I fix this?

Comment: I suggest discarding inline event handlers like `<td ... onclick` and just use `$(selector).on('click', function(){...})` to add event handlers. You can also use `$(selector).trigger('click')` from another handler to call an event handler on another element (which looks like what you might be doing here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change that function to this:

```
function clickedTD(){
  $(".questionsClass").css("background-color","#eee");
  $(".questionsClass").css("color","black");

  $(this).css("background-color","#5bc0de");
  $(this).css("color","white");
}
```

The reason it didn't work is that this function is adding a click event callback that will trigger when the the class is clicked. Meaning that all clicks after the first will produce the desired outcome.

Alternatively you could just add this code and remove the function and the function call from the onclick attribute.

```
$(".questionsClass").click(function(){
  $(".questionsClass").css("background-color","#eee");
  $(".questionsClass").css("color","black");

  $(this).css("background-color","#5bc0de");
  $(this).css("color","white");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Really, you only need to attach one function to the click event handler - here's how I would approach it:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="questionsClass" data-question-id="1">This is my Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="questionsClass" data-question-id="2">This is my Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="questionsClass" data-question-id="3">This is my Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="questionsClass" data-question-id="4">This is my Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="questionsClass" data-question-id="5">This is my Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="questionsClass" data-question-id="6">This is my Row</td>
    </tr>
</table>

$(".questionsClass").on('click', function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var $this         = $(this),
        dQuestionID   = $this.attr('data-question-id');    

       alert(dQuestionID);
    $(".questionsClass").css("background-color","#eee").css("color","black");

    $this.css("background-color","#5bc0de").css("color","white"); 

});
```

Here's a quick JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sbritton/HEZeB/1/